# Reading data continuously from NfcaA tag using background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nfc

I am trying to read some data from an nfcA tag by sending it a command and then get the response after every 4 seconds. The processing is done in background thread  called from  onNewIntent(). An handler will then be use to update the UI thread.This is my code so far. I am having difficulty getting the thread part to work. Not getting any update from the response.

When i uninstalled the app and restarted my phone i was able to get the response from the tag. Leaving the phone and tag connected send the response for a few mins. It throws java.io.IOException,
- after sending the response for a few mins
- if i move the phone away from the tag and then try to reconnect.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private int PENDING_INTENT_TECH_DISCOVERED = 1;
    private TextView mNfcTech, temp, vol, amb_temp;
    private Utility myUtils = new Utility();
    // Hold the 16 bytes response from the fast_read command
    private byte[] response = new byte[16];
    // Create a Handler object
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    // Update interval
    private int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 2000;
    private static Tag detectedTag;
    boolean threadRun = true;
    public static final String TAG = "nfc";
    private TextView mTextView;
    private NfcAdapter mNfcAdapter;

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialise the textview controls
        mNfcTech = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nfc_technology_tv);
        temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
        vol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.vol);
        amb_temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amb_temp);

        // Get the device nfc adpater
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);

        if (hasNfc()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is available.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available on this device. This application may not work correctly.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // get the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action =intent.getAction();
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
            handleIntent(intent);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setupForegroundDispatch();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        /**
         * Call this before onPause, otherwise an IllegalArgumentException is thrown as well.
         */
        stopForegroundDispatch();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        /**
         * This method gets called, when a new Intent gets associated with the current activity instance.
         * Instead of creating a new activity, onNewIntent will be called. Called
         * when the user attaches a Tag to the device.
         */
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    // Handle the intent once tag comes in contact with phone
    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

        // TODO: handle Intent
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
            // In case we would still use the Tech Discovered Intent
            detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);

            // start running the Thread
            backgroundExecution();

        }
    }

    public void setupForegroundDispatch() {

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);

        IntentFilter techFilter = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED);

        IntentFilter[] intentFilter = new IntentFilter[]{techFilter};

        String[][] techList = new String[][]{
                new String[]{android.nfc.tech.NfcA.class.getName()}

        };
        mNfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pi, intentFilter, techList);

    }

    public void stopForegroundDispatch() {
        mNfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    // Check if nfc is available for the device and is enabled.
    public boolean hasNfc() {
        boolean hasFeature = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_NFC);
        boolean isEnabled = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this).isEnabled();
        return hasFeature && isEnabled;
    }


    public void backgroundExecution() {

        // This moves the time consuming operation to a child thread.
        Thread thread = new Thread(doBackgroundThreadProcessing);
        thread.start();

    }

    // Runnable that executes the background processing method.
    private Runnable doBackgroundThreadProcessing = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {


            NfcA nfca = NfcA.get(detectedTag);
            // nfca fast_read command
            byte[] command = new byte[]{0x3A, 0x04C, 0x04F};
            // use for control stop/start of the thread
            boolean keepRunning = true;
            // run until as to stop
            while(keepRunning){
                // check if null
               // if (nfca != null) {
                if (!nfca.isConnected()){
                    try {
                        nfca.connect();
                        String TAG = "connect";
                        Log.i(TAG, "connected to the tag");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                    }
                    if (nfca.isConnected()) {
                        try {
                            // send command and get the response
                            response = nfca.transceive(command);
                            // log response to the console
                            String myStr = myUtils.bytesToHex(response);
                            String TAG = "fastRead";
                            Log.i(TAG, "Response receive :" + myStr);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                nfca.close();
                                // log closing to the console
                                String TAG = "close";
                                Log.i(TAG,"closing the connection");
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
                            }
                            // stop the
                           // keepRunning = false;
                            // put the thread to sleep for 4 sec
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(4000);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    };
}
`
```

Comment: Your code does not do any updates on the UI thread, so what's your actual question?

Comment: Hi Michael. The code for the UI Thread updates is not implemented yet. I'm  reading the response from the tag and displaying it in the log.i "Response receive" for error checking.  I cant seem to get and any response from the tag.

Comment: So you get an IOException instead of the response or does the traceive method succeed (returning null or some value that you did not expect) as a result of the FAST_READ command? DOes your tag support FAST_READ and does it have at least 0x4F pages?

Comment: Yes I do get an IOException(please see edited post above). The tag I am using is from NXP and it does support FAST_READ. Also the tag has 0xFF pages. Thanks